# Getting Initial Value for LiveData Always Returning Null

Tags: java, android, android-room, synchronous, android-livedata

I am trying to load the **loggedInUser** from the Local Room Database, when the App starts. I would like to skip prompting user to log-in if the saved **Authentication Token** of the previously saved user is still valid!

So, from the **DAO**, I want to return a **LiveData** object containing the **previously logged-in user**, then **observe** it for subsequent changes. The challenge I have is that the method to get the currently logged-in user **always returns null** if I wrap the result inside a **LiveData**, but it returns the expected user if returned as a **POJO**.

How can I force **LiveData** to run **synchronously** just to **initialize** the **value** and then thereafter **listen to subsequent changes**? I really want to combine the two behaviors as the authentication may be **invalidated** by a **background syncing task** or when the **user logs out**(these actions will either replace or update the saved token and I would like to be **reactive** to such **updates** with the help of **LiveData**).

Here is what I have tried so far:

**AuthorizationDAO.java**

```
public interface AuthorizationDAO {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Authorization LIMIT 1") //Assume only one Authentication token will exist at any given time
    LiveData<Authorization> getLoggedInUser(); //I want to keep this behaviour

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    long insertAuth(Authorization authorization);

    @Update
    void logoutCurrentUser(Authorization authorization);


}
```

**AuthorizationRepository.java**

```
public class AuthorizationRepository {
    private AuthorizationDAO mAuthorizationDAO;

    private MutableLiveData<Authorization> mAuthorization = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public AuthorizationRepository(Application application){

        AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application);

        this.mAuthorizationDAO = db.mAuthorizationDAO();
    }

    public LiveData<Authorization> getLoggedInUser(){
               mAuthorization.postValue(mAuthorizationDAO.getLoggedInUser().getValue()); //this is always null at startup
        return this.mAuthorization;
    }
```

**AuthorizationViewModel.java**

```
public class AuthorizationViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private AuthorizationRepository mAuthorizationRepository;

    private LiveData<Resource<Authorization>> mAuthorization;
    private LiveData<Authorization> loggedInUserAuth;

    public AuthorizationViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        this.mAuthorizationRepository = new AuthorizationRepository(application);

    }
    public void init(){
        this.loggedInUserAuth = this.mAuthorizationRepository.getLoggedInUser();
    }
    public LiveData<Authorization> getLoggedInUserAuth() {
        return this.loggedInUserAuth;
    }
}
```

**AppActivity.java**

```
public class AppActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public AuthorizationViewModel mAuthorizationViewModel;
    public  @Nullable Authorization mAuthorization;
    private NavController mNavController;
    private NavHostFragment mNavHostFragment;
    private BottomNavigationView mBottomNavigationView;
    private boolean mIsLoggedIn;
    private ActivityAppBinding mBinding;
    private boolean mIsTokenExpired;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_app);

        mNavHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.app_nav_host_fragment);
        mNavController = mNavHostFragment.getNavController();

        mBottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_bottom_nav_view);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(mBottomNavigationView, mNavController);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>9){

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        mAuthorizationViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AuthorizationViewModel.class);

        mAuthorizationViewModel.init(); //Here I want to load user synchronously before the rest happens and then on next line observe the same object

        mAuthorizationViewModel.getLoggedInUserAuth().observe(this, new Observer<Authorization>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Authorization authorization) {
                mBinding.setViewModel(authorization);
                mIsLoggedIn = authorization == null? false: authorization.isLoggedIn();
                mIsTokenExpired = authorization == null ? true : authorization.isTokenExpired();
                if(!mIsLoggedIn || mIsTokenExpired){
                    if (authorization != null){

                        Log.i("CurrentAuth", "mIsLoggedIn?: "+authorization.isLoggedIn());
                        Log.i("CurrentAuth", "isTokenExpired?: "+authorization.isTokenExpired());
                        Log.i("CurrentAuth", "tokenCurrentTime?: "+ Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                        Log.i("CurrentAuth", "tokenIssuedAt?: "+ authorization.getIat());
                        Log.i("CurrentAuth", "tokenExpiresAt?: "+ authorization.getExp());
                    }
                    mNavController.navigate(R.id.start_login);
                }
            }
        });
```

As you can see, I am calling **mAuthorizationViewModel.init()** so I can **load or initialize** the **loggedInUserAuth** from the **local database**, and then **observe** the same **LiveData** instance with **mAuthorizationViewModel.getLoggedInUserAuth().observe()** on the next line! But the value returned for **loggedInUserAuth** is **always null**!

*Kindly help, thanks!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a getter method of `mAuthorization` in class `AuthorizationRepository`

```
public MutableLiveData<Authorization> getAuthorizationResult() {
   return mAuthorization;
}
```

Then modify your `AuthorizationViewModel` class like below

```
public void init() {
    mAuthorizationRepository.getLoggedInUser();
}

public LiveData<Authorization> getLoggedInUserAuth() {
    return mAuthorizationRepository.getAuthorizationResult();
}
```

Comment: thank you for refactoring the code. It looks much more cleaner and in logical order but I am still getting null when I inspect **mAuthorization** in the ViewModel. It seems this line of code in the **AuthorizationRepository** does not execute to completion and always returns null :         `mAuthorization.postValue(mAuthorizationDAO.getLoggedInUser().getValue());`

Comment: When does this `mAuthorizationDAO.getLoggedInUser()` return proper value other than null ?

Comment: It returns a proper value when the **DAO method's return type** is not wrapped in **LiveData**!

Comment: Try with this `public LiveData<Authorization> getLoggedInUser(){
 this.mAuthorization = mAuthorizationDAO.getLoggedInUser();
 return this.mAuthorization;
}` Keep your code like how you posted in question

Comment: **mAuthorization** is **MutableLiveData** while **mAuthorizationDAO.getLoggedInUser()** returns a **LiveData** so it raises **type incompatibility error**.

Comment: And when I change the return type of the **DAO** as `MutableLiveData<Authorization>` I get the error: `Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type`

Comment: Instead of changing return type of dao, change AuthorizationRepository  mAuthorization type to Livedata. in case you have github code share the link if feasible.

Comment: Here is the [link to github repo](https://github.com/BantuLab/WaterMetreReader/blob/f787b2077bb3104e7f691b505341679dfc3966bb/app/src/main/java/com/bantulogic/core/watermetrereader/data/repository/AuthorizationRepository.java#L48)

Comment: Are you sure at the moment you calling `getLoggedInUser` method value is present in your database?. for me this query even returns null **SELECT * FROM Authorization LIMIT 1**

Comment: Yes, the value is present in the database and running the same query via adb sqlite3 shell gives me the record. Also if I return a non-LiveData object from the DAO method, I get the expected result. You are getting null result because you probably have no tables created on your emulator and no token saved! When the App runs and you successfully login, the API returns a token which the App saves and then can be used for subsequent requests to the API. The saved token is also being used to authenticate the user to the App on the device, as long as it is still valid.

Comment: your comment on changing the return type to **LiveData** led me to the answer, just with a few cleanups. I will post the working code snippets, and I must say thanks man. You saved me lots of hours...

Comment: @Chaiwa please accept the answer if it helped you to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved this problem with great help from @Krishna, and here are the main points:

1. The **DAO method** should return **LiveData**
2. In the **Repository class**, create a **LiveData private member variable** and not **MutableLiveData**(this is because we will be mutating database record via updates/inserts). The member variable will hold a reference to a **LiveData** object returned by the **DAO Method**
3. In the **Repository's constructor**, *initialize* the **LiveData** object to the result returned by the **DAO method**. This way, every time the activity starts, the currently saved record will be loaded
4. In the **Repository class**, create a **getter** which will expose the **LiveData** object to the **ViewModel**
5. In the **ViewModel class**, create a method which will expose the **LiveData** object to the **View Controller (activity or fragment)**
6. In the **Activity or Fragment**, *simply listen or subscribe* to changes on the **LiveData** exposed by the **Accessor Method** provided by the **ViewModel**
7. The **DAO** can also expose a method to update the **LiveData**, allowing the *Repository* via the *ViewModel* to enable the *Activity or Fragment* to send updates to the *LiveData*, at the same time keeping all listeners *reactive*!

Here is the working code for this scenario:

**AuthorizationDAO.java**

```
public interface AuthorizationDAO {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Authorization LIMIT 1") //Assume only one Authentication token will exist at any given time
    LiveData<Authorization> getLoggedInUser(); //I want to keep this behaviour

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    long insertAuth(Authorization authorization);

    @Update
    void logoutCurrentUser(Authorization authorization); //this will be used to toggle login status by Activity or Fragment
}
```

**AuthorizationRepository.java**

```
public class AuthorizationRepository {
    private AuthorizationDAO mAuthorizationDAO;
    private AuthorizationWebAPI mAuthorizationWebAPI;
    private LiveData<Authorization> mAuthorization; //reference to returned LiveData

    public AuthorizationRepository(Application application){
        AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        this.mAuthorizationDAO = db.mAuthorizationDAO();
        this.mAuthorization = mAuthorizationDAO.getLoggedInUser(); //initialize LiveData
    }
    public LiveData<Authorization> getAuthorizationResult() { //getter exposing LiveData
        return mAuthorization;
    }
    public void logoutCurrentUser(){ //toggle login status
        if (this.mAuthorization != null){
            AppExecutors.getInstance().getDiskIO().execute(()->{
                Authorization mAuthorizationObj = this.mAuthorization.getValue();
                mAuthorizationObj.setLoggedIn(false);
                mAuthorizationDAO.logoutCurrentUser(mAuthorizationObj); //update LiveData and changes will be broadcast to all listeners
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**AuthorizationViewModel.java**

```
public class AuthorizationViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private AuthorizationRepository mAuthorizationRepository;

    public AuthorizationViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        this.mAuthorizationRepository = new AuthorizationRepository(application);
    }
    public LiveData<Authorization> getLoggedInUserAuth() { //exposes LiveData to the Activity or Fragment
        return mAuthorizationRepository.getAuthorizationResult();
    }
    public void logoutCurrentUser(){ //allows activity or fragment to toggle login status
        this.mAuthorizationRepository.logoutCurrentUser();
    }
}
```

**AppActivity.java**

```
public class AppActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public AuthorizationViewModel mAuthorizationViewModel;
    public  @Nullable Authorization mAuthorization;
    private NavController mNavController;
    private NavHostFragment mNavHostFragment;
    private BottomNavigationView mBottomNavigationView;
    private boolean mIsLoggedIn;
    private ActivityAppBinding mBinding;
    private boolean mIsTokenExpired;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_app);

        mNavHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.app_nav_host_fragment);
        mNavController = mNavHostFragment.getNavController();

        mBottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_bottom_nav_view);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(mBottomNavigationView, mNavController);

        mAuthorizationViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AuthorizationViewModel.class);

        mAuthorizationViewModel.getLoggedInUserAuth().observe(this, new Observer<Authorization>() { //Observe changes to Authorization LiveData exposed by getLoggedInUserAuth()
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Authorization authorization) {
                mBinding.setViewModel(authorization);
                mIsLoggedIn = authorization == null? false: authorization.isLoggedIn();
                mIsTokenExpired = authorization == null ? true : authorization.isTokenExpired();
                if(!mIsLoggedIn || mIsTokenExpired){
                    if (authorization != null){
                        Log.i("CurrentAuth", "tokenExpiresAt?: "+ authorization.getExp());
                    }
                    mNavController.navigate(R.id.start_login); //every time authorization is changed, we check if valid else we react by prompting user to login
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**LogoutFragment.java**

```
public class LogoutFragment extends Fragment {

    private AuthorizationViewModel mAuthorizationViewModel;
    private Authorization mAuth;
    private FragmentLogoutBinding mBinding;

    public LogoutFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mAuthorizationViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(AuthorizationViewModel.class);
        mAuthorizationViewModel.getLoggedInUserAuth().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<Authorization>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Authorization authorization) {
                mAuth = authorization;
            }
        });
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_logout,container,false);
        View view = mBinding.getRoot();
        mBinding.setViewModel(mAuth);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                .setTitle(R.string.title_logout_fragment)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        mAuthorizationViewModel.logoutCurrentUser(); //toggle login status, this will mutate LiveData by updating the database record then UI will react and call login fragment
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.cancel();
                        Navigation.findNavController(view).popBackStack();
                    }
                })
                .setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's too late but might help someone.

I faced the same issue when I did this

```
MyDao myDao;
private LiveData<List<T>> liveList;
//in constructor of repo after initializing myDao;
    this.liveList = myDao.getAllData();
//somewhere in repo
    for(T t : liveList.getValue()){/*computation*/}
```

and this is how I solved it

```
MyDao myDao;
//in constructor of repo don't do this because called on main thread
    this.list = myDao.getAll();
//in constructor of repo initialize your Dao (in this case myDao)
//somewhere in repo  (must not be on main thread)
    for(T t : myDao.getAll()){/*computation*/} //do this on background thread
```

in MyDao

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM myTable")
List<T> getAll();
@Query("SELECT * FROM myTable")
LiveData<List<T>> getAllData();
```

Or, if you are accessing the liveList in some other place (than repository) then you must set an observer for the same